# isinstance alternative to check classes which return flase on being the parent or subclass

Tags: python, object, isinstance

Let me first show how `isinstance()` works

```
class superclass:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

class subclass(p):
    pass

obj = subclass("pinoy")
```

This is how isinstance works

```
>>> isinstance (obj, superclass)
True
```

Here, `obj` is mainly a instance of `subclass`. Since, `subclass` inherits from `superclass`,

`isinstance(obj, superclass)` returns `True`

Is there any, way that would check if a object mainly belongs to the class specified and return `Flase` otherwise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between type() and isinstance()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `type`:

```
class superclass:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

class subclass(superclass):
    pass
obj = subclass("pinoy")

print(type(obj))
#<class '__main__.subclass'>

type(obj) == subclass
# True

type(obj) == superclass
# False
```